# Most Performant Way to Execute Many dml Statements in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have some legacy code that is currently generating significant lists (~10,000) SQLAlchemy DML statements and then iterating over the list and executing them one by one. I.e.

```py
statements = get_long_list_of_statements()
for statement in statements:
   engine.execute(statement)
```

This is taking much longer than it needs to because the statements aren't being batched. But also I can't find anything that suggests SQLAlchemy supports batching DML statements.

Getting a raw connection, grabbing a cursor, and doing `cursor.executemany(statements, None)` is the only thing I've found that doesn't raise an exception. But it also doesn't appear to affect the database. Even after committing and closing the connection.

Is there an efficient (or at least more efficient) way in SQLALchemy to batch a group of DML statements?

The statements are a mix of `Delte`, `Insert`, and `Update`, the DB is MySQL 8.0, and I'm using SQLAlchemy 1.4 if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider to execute DML statements inside MySQL as stored routines, stored functions.

These routines and functions are parsed once and stored inside the database. They could be called and executed repeatedly inside the database server.

On the other hand, if you send DML statements from a client (such as SQLAlchemy, mysql), the these statements would be transmitted across network or process, parsed and then executed. Depending on the number of cached statements inside the database server, these statements would be parsed every time they are transmitted to the database server. This significantly slow down the overall performance of your work.

Also avoid complicated `IF ... THEN ... ELSE ... END IF` as MySQL still evaluates unmatched statements. Write short stored routune. See [1].

Examples:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `Customer_select` (
    customerId  INT,
)
BEGIN
    SELECT CustomerID, 
           Name,
           CompanyName
      FROM Customers
     WHERE CustomerID = customerId
END
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `Customer_insert` (
    customerId  INT,
    name        VARCHAR(100),
    companyName VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Customers(
        Name,
        CompanyName
    )
    VALUES (
        name,
        companyName
    )
END
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `Customer_update` (
    customerId  INT,
    name        VARCHAR(100),
    companyName VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE Customers,
       SET Name    = name,
           Company = company
     WHERE CustomerID = customerId
END
```

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE `Customer_delete` (
    customerId  INT
)
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM Customers,
     WHERE CustomerID = customerId
END
```

You could just start writing a few stored routines to check the performance improvement before making big changes to your code.

Do take note of restrictions on stored programs. See [2].

1. https://www.percona.com/blog/2018/07/12/why-mysql-stored-procedures-functions-triggers-bad-performance/
2. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-reslimits-excerpt/8.0/en/stored-program-restrictions.html